# Different connection strings when primary server has error

Tags: database, string, connection, sitecore

has anybody some Idea how to create at my website (running on sitecore) two connectionStings and switch between them base on server error?

When I have two DB servers. Server A and Server B (there is a replication between all databases). My website is primary connected to server A. I need to find some solution how to connect website to Server B for when server A will be for example turned off or will not response from any other way.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a failover partner in your connection string:

```
Data Source=MainServer;Failover Partner=SecondaryServer;
```

Refer to section 3.8 of the scaling guide ([PDF link here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/66/scaling_guide_sc66-a4.pdf))